# How do I create tag with certain commits and push it to origin?

Tags: git, tags, commit

Say the current log in my gerrit looks like the following:

- commit10 (master)
- commit9
- commit8
- commit7
- commit6 v1.72.0
- commit5
- commit4 v1.71.0
- commit3
- commit2
- commit1

My goal is to create a new tag (v1.73.0) that should contain commit8 and commit9 and push it to origin. I was told to create a new local branch based on the latest stable tag and cherry-pick the necessary commits and tag it up. However, I am having some problem pushing the tag up to master.

Here's what I've done:

- create local branch based on the latest tag: git checkout -b branchforv1.73.0 v1.72.0
- cherry-pick commit8 and commit9
- create new tag: git tag v1.73.0

...so now, how do I push v1.73.0 to master?

Result:

- commit10 (master)
- commit7
- commit9 v1.73.0
- commit8
- commit6 v1.72.0
- commit5
- commit4 v1.71.0
- commit3
- commit2
- commit1

Comment: *a new tag (v1.73.0) that should contain commit8 and commit9 [...]* A tag cannot point to multiple commits; only one.

Comment: When you say, "push it to master", do you mean "push it to origin" (or some other remote)?

Comment: i meant "push it to origin".

Answer (score 81, accepted):

### How tags work

In git, each tag is said to "point to" a (one, single) commit.  In fact, the same is true of a branch: a branch name *also* just points to one commit.

What makes this work is two things:

- each commit also points to another commit (or perhaps several), and
- for branches (and *only* for branches), the commit to which the branch points "moves forward" automatically.  That is, as you add new commits—in some ways, that's mostly all git does: add new commits to its collective, sort of like the Borg from the old Star Trek TNG series—whatever branch you're on, that's the branch that gets re-adjusted to point to the new commit.

Thus, the main difference between a branch and a tag is that a tag does not move.

To see how this works, consider a simple git repository with just three commits.  Let's label these commits `A`, `B`, and `C`.  The first commit (`A`) points to nothing, as it's the first commit, and branch `master` points to `A`:

```
A   <-- master
```

When you make the second commit, git creates `B` pointing back to `A`, and advances the branch name to point to `B`:

```
A <- B   <-- master
```

Then when you make a third commit, git again makes it point back to its parent commit, and advances the branch:

```
A <- B <- C   <-- master
```

If you make a tag now, that tag will, by default, point to commit `C`:

```
A <- B <- C   <-- master
          ^
          |
   tag: sometag
```

If you then make a new commit `D`, git advances the *branch*, but not the tag:

```
A <- B <- C <- D   <-- master
          ^
          |
   tag: sometag
```

You can, at any time, create or delete any tag pointing to any particular commit:

```
$ git tag -d sometag
```

will delete tag `sometag`, after which:

```
$ git tag sometag master~2
```

will add `sometag` pointing to commit `B`.<sup>1</sup>

(We've just proven that a tag *can* move.  The real difference is that tags are not *expected* to move, while branches are; and git won't move tags automatically.<sup>2</sup>  Branches are generally expected to move in a "forward" direction, i.e., if `master` used to point to commit `C` and now points to commit `D`, commit `C` should usually be found by starting at `D` and working backwards.  Any time you move a branch so that this rule is violated, you're "rewriting history"; see other articles for when this is fine, and when it causes people trouble.)

### Pushing tags

When you use `git push`, what you're really doing is instructing some other git repository to take any new commits you have that they don't, and then set some name(s)—usually branches and/or tags—to point to some commits (one each) in the resulting collection.<sup>3</sup>  These names (branches, tags, and so on) are called "references" in general, but let's just use "branch" and "tag" for now.

The argument after `git push` names the repository (generally via a "remote" name, like `origin`) to push-to.  If you leave it out, git will try to figure one out, but if you want to add a branch or tag name, you need to include it explicitly, since the first word here is assumed to be the remote-name.  (That is, `git push master` tries to use `master` as a remote-name rather than a branch-name.)

To push *all* your tags, you can simply add `--tags` to your `git push` command:

```
git push --tags origin
```

To push a *specific* tag, you can name it:

```
git push origin sometag
```

just as you can push a specific branch:

```
git push origin master
```

(In fact, that fourth argument is a *pair* of names, like `master:master` or `sometag:sometag`, but it defaults to using the same name on both sides in most cases.<sup>4</sup>)

You can leave out the name `origin` if you don't need it to make all the arguments, e.g., `git push --tags` is the same as `git push --tags origin` (assuming all your pushes go to `origin`, anyway).

#### Putting it together

To set a tag in the remote, first set it locally, with `git tag name commit-identifier`.  Use whatever viewer you like to make sure it's set correctly.  Then push it, with either `git push origin name` or `git push --tags`.

---

<sup>1</sup>The `master~2` syntax instructs git to start at the commit found via `master`, then back up two steps.  You could instead write the raw SHA-1 for commit `B` here.

<sup>2</sup>Old versions of git (pre 1.8.4) accidentally applied branch rules to tags when pushing (on the remote side, i.e., they let a tag move if it was a "fast forward").

<sup>3</sup>In some cases, you can point a name to an "annotated tag", and there's nothing preventing a name from pointing at a "tree" or "blob" object either, but that's not a normal setup.

<sup>4</sup>Actually the default *dst* refspec for a branch is complicated: it depends on your `push.default` configuration, and whether there is a `remote.repository.push` setting, and whether there is an upstream configured, and so on.  For tags, the rules are simpler since there's no such thing as an "upstream".

Comment: Is there any convention regarding the branch to which a tag points to? Can I have tags pointing to different branches, or only to `master`?

Comment: @AmyPellegrini: tags *don't* point to branches. Once the tag is made, any branches are irrelevant. Tags point to *commits*. See the updated drawing in the answer.

Comment: @torek Yeah, I get that, I'm just wondering how you organise the tags in a consistent manner to enable automated releases/deploys. I would have thought that releases are triggered from a specific branch, rather than a tag, but tags seem more convenient. Basically I want each tag to match a specific version, and every version by default automatically released to a given environment.

Comment: @AmyPellegrini Well, that depends on your release process. There are too many to just arbitrarily say "use process X". One that I liked, though, back in about 2015 or so, was: we made a branch named `release/1.0`, then a *tag* named `release/1.0.rc0`. Fix some bugs and tag `release/1.0.rc1`, and so on up until we had the actual release. Then we'd *delete* the `release/1.0` branch entirely because you were not to develop on it: instead, there is a new branch `release/1.1` pointing to the commit tagged as `release-1.0`.

Comment: We went through a few iterations of changing the names around a bit, and I think ended up using `rc/x.y` as branch and/or tag names, instead of `release/`, until the releases happened, and called the final release tags `release/x.y`. That way the actual releases were grouped together, away from the branches. But this particular startup company ran out of funds so this never got past 0.x anyway. :-)

Answer (score 45):

Here is a concrete example:

```
git add .
git commit -m "some description"
git tag v0.1.9 # or any other text
git push origin master # push the commit
git push --tags origin # push the tags
```

Comment: `git push --tags origin` has pushed all local tags. Can we specify the one which we want to push?

Answer (score 7):

This is what you want

```
git add .
git commit -m "commit10"
git tag -a v1.73.0 -m "Latest release (or some message)"
git push origin master
git push origin v1.73.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Once you've created the tag (which it looks like you've done), simply run

```
git push --tags origin
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work as expected. Anyway, thanks but I went with a different route by creating a remote branch with the latest tag, pull that branch onto my local, cherry pick commits, push that branch, create and push a new tag.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a tag is simple here's a command to do that :-

Example:

```
git tag -a v1.0 7cceb02 -m "Your message here"
```

Where `7cceb02` is the beginning part of the commit id.

You can then push the tag using `git push origin v1.0`.

You can do `git log` to show all the commit id's in your current branch.